# How to run custom build event in custom c# project during TFS build

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, vsix

I have created a custom c# project for Visual Studio 2013 which carries out some additional steps during the build (creates nuget file from bin dir). As this is going to be used by other teams it is part of the code and not the Post Build Events. It works fine in Visual Studio, however when the code is run via our automated TFS process it does not carry out the custom actions.

My code is part of the custom project installed via VSIX which implements the DTE2.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone event.

Do I need to set up to listen for a different event for using TFS builds?

Comment: TFS doesn't build using VS, these really need to be Post Build Events or After build target or some custom MSBuild task. The other option is you have to build a new TFS build activity to do this once compilation is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case